# how to scrape data from json file which is givig below

Tags: json, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scrapign data from redfin real estate website in which some data are in javascript contents
and some are in html
This is the program

## packages

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import urllib
import os
import json
import datetime

# property scraper class
class ResidentialSale(scrapy.Spider):
    # scraper name
    name = 'therapists'
    base_url = 'https://www.redfin.com/city/11203/CA/Los-Angeles'        

    # headers
    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
    }
    try:
       os.remove('redfin1.csv')
    except OSError:
       pass   
    # custom settings
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUEST_PER_DOMAIN': 2,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1
    }

    # general crawler
    def start_requests(self):
       
            # initial HTTP request
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=self.base_url,
                headers=self.headers,
               
                callback=self.parse
            )
            
    def  parse(self,response):       
         
         properties = [script for script in response.css('script').getall() if '<script type="application/ld+json">' in script]
         for prop in properties:
           prop = prop.split('<script type="application/ld+json">')[-1]
           prop=prop.split('</script>')[0]
           prop = json.loads(prop)
           prop = json.dumps(prop, indent = 2)
           print(prop)
           #print(prop['@context']['address'])
           #for card in prop:
              #print(card)
            
    
# main driver
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run scraper
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(ResidentialSale)
    process.start()
```

I want to extract some data from the js content. If you run this program in your system than the json fiel which you get i want soem data like   name, url, location, address, etc and how to get data from this json file if i want to get from.

Comment: where exactly is `'redfin.html'` coming from?

Comment: it is the local html of the website page that i have downloaded and checking the data offline by using scrapy.

Comment: Now i just remove the file and check it now

Comment: that code is giving the error: `ReactorNotRestartable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built in  [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to extract the data

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import urllib
import os
import json
import datetime

# property scraper class
class ResidentialSale(scrapy.Spider):
    # scraper name
    name = 'therapists'
    base_url = 'https://www.redfin.com/city/11203/CA/Los-Angeles'

    # headers
    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
    }
    try:
       os.remove('redfin1.csv')
    except OSError:
       pass
    # custom settings
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUEST_PER_DOMAIN': 2,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1
    }

    # general crawler
    def start_requests(self):

            # initial HTTP request
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=self.base_url,
                headers=self.headers,

                callback=self.parse
            )

    def  parse(self,response):
        properties = [script for script in response.css('script').getall() if '<script type="application/ld+json">' in script]
        for prop in properties:
            prop = prop.split('<script type="application/ld+json">')[-1]
            prop=prop.split('</script>')[0]
            prop = json.loads(prop)

            for data in prop:
                    if isinstance(data, dict):
                        yield {
                            'Name': data['name'],
                            'Url': data['url'],
                            'Address': data.get('address', ''),

                        }
      

# main driver
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run scraper
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(ResidentialSale)
    process.start()
```

### some output

```
{'Name': '4060 Glencoe Ave #226, Marina Del Rey, CA 90292', 'Url': '/CA/Marina-Del-Rey/4060-Glencoe-Ave-90292/unit-226/home/8179466', 'Address': {'@type': 'PostalAddress', 'streetAddress': '4060 Glencoe Ave #226', 'addressLocality': 'Marina Del Rey', 'addressRegion': 'CA', 'postalCode': '90292', 'addressCountry': 'US'}}
```

Comment: Thank you i check this now an dit starts working.

Comment: Please Upvote,accept this/any Answer which is useful to you

Comment: Thanks, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments